# Getting bearer token for Discord API

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord

Im trying to get a list of all channels in my discord server using the discord api. However im getting a 401 no access in my api client, probably because I have the wrong api key, but I have no clue how to get a working key. Below you see my api request.

[image: api request with 401 error1]

I read in the docs of discord that I need a oAuth2 token, but I just can't seem to figure how to get that token..

Thanks for the replies,

Boudewijn Bout

Answer (score -1):

To make a request to the Discord API you must include a **token** in the headers:
`Authorization: TOKEN`.
To get a valid token **open DevTools** (press F12), go to the **network** tab, and send a random message to your friend or server. Then you will see that a new row appeared in the network tab. Click on that row then go to its headers and find the **authorization** header, the value of that header is token. If you have any questions about the Discord API feel free to DM me on Discord - Koll Potato#2437.